# Running Panda3D on Python 2.6

Tags: python, panda3d

I just got Panda3D for the first time. I deleted the included Python version. In my Python dir, I put a file `panda.pth` that looks like this:

```
C:\Panda3D-1.6.2
C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\bin
```

But when I run `import direct.directbase.DirectStart`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import direct.directbase.DirectStart
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\direct\directbase\DirectStart.py", line 3, in <module>
    from direct.showbase import ShowBase
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandac.PandaModules import *
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\pandac\PandaModules.py", line 1, in <module>
    from libpandaexpressModules import *
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\pandac\libpandaexpressModules.py", line 1, in <module>
    from extension_native_helpers import *
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\pandac\extension_native_helpers.py", line 75, in <module>
    Dtool_PreloadDLL("libpandaexpress")
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.6.2\pandac\extension_native_helpers.py", line 73, in Dtool_PreloadDLL
    imp.load_dynamic(module, pathname)
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with me using Python 2.6. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wait for the upcoming 1.7.0 release, it will be compiled against Python 2.6 - see [this thread](http://www.panda3d.org/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?p=42778&sid=d77e7708ac0d9d3f79c19c0fcd5c4621).

Comment: Interesting. Is there an estimate on when it will come out?

Answer (score 3):

Python extensions aren't binary compatible across major releases.  Your options are:

A. Recompile panda3d for python 2.6.

B. Use python 2.5.

No way around it.